pip install RandomWords: "No module named 'setuptools.command.test'"
I'm using pip 24.2 and Python 3.12.4. I want to install this:
$ pip install RandomWords

Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

from setuptools.command.test import test as TestCommand
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools.command.test'

 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

The real problem is that Setuptools tries to provide this all-encompassing build interface, almost all of which is now deprecated (you aren't supposed to run setup.py directly, but only allow it to power Setuptools as a build backend). So developers end up with stuff in their setup.py file that's completely irrelevant to end users actually installing the package (from an sdist).

I made a pull request to fix this issue in the project cited (along with generally attempting to modernize its build process and make further recommendations to the author).

It seems that their package is broken. This is because in setup.py they are doing
from setuptools.command.test import test as TestCommand

but setuptools.command.test was removed on 28 Jul 2024 (yesterday):
https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/stable/history.html#v72-0-0
Here's a similar issue on the official GitHub repo: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/4519

To solve it locally do one of the following:

downgrade your setuptools as @reza.safiyat suggested;
use a project manager (like Poetry or Hatch) and pin setuptools = "<72.0.0".


UPDATE
setuptools 72.0.0 has been yanked (https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/72.0.0/#history) and the removal of command.test has been postponed to November 15.
Everything should work as it did yesterday (with the addition of a new big warning, hopefully).

pinning setuptools does not work for mee, poetry install tries to install latest setuptools anyway

From one of my poetry-handled projects: (1) poetry show setuptools -> 65.6.3, (2) added setuptools = "<50.0.0" under [tool.poetry.dependencies], (3) poetry update setuptools, (4) poetry show setuptools -> 49.6.0.

Instead of setuptools = "<50.0.0", you could probably do with setuptools = "<72.0.0" to use the latest setuptools without this issue.

Yes sure, but since in my example I was trying to downgrade from version 65.6.3, using <72.0.0 would have done nothing

@jossefaz maybe this will help https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/4519#issuecomment-2255784138

@VanitySlug-codidact.com You mean this?

Investigating the project further, there's clearly no reason it needs a setup.py at all, and no reason why it can't ship a wheel (which Pip would by default prefer over the sdist). It's pure Python code, and making the end user "build" that code wastes time and obscures the project metadata.

As far as I can tell, the only reason it's using setuptools.command.test anyway is so that the developer has the convenience of running setup.py test instead of python -m pytest --strict-markers --verbose --tb=long (which could be turned into a shell alias anyway).

@KarlKnechtel That too, yes. But also more generally speaking, it's annoying how libraries/frameworks/etc are constantly changing and breaking things, and how project that rely on them keep blindly relying on them.

It’s probably worth pointing out that while the feature has been removed just yesterday was already deprecated 5 years prior.

This module was removed from in this commit.
Using setuptools<72.0.0 will alleviate this problem.
Steps you may use once you have sourced the relevant python environment:
# Install setuptools below v72.0.0. Add `-U` after `install` in case you want to upgrade to a version below 72.0.0, if you already have setuptools installed.
python -m pip install 'setuptools<72.0.0'
# Install RandomWords.
python -m pip install RandomWords


Doesn't seem to work for poetry though.

Try the helpful comment by @ychiucco.

Edit
setuptools 72.0.0 has been yanked

https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/72.0.0/#history
Rerun your pipelines all good now.


This bug arises from changes made to setuptools.command.test in the 72.0.0 update of setuptools. For more details, refer to the setuptools · PyPI page. One of the dependencies used in this repository, Ch00k/ffmpy: Pythonic interface for FFmpeg/FFprobe command line, utilizes setuptools.command.test.
As a temporary solution, I forked the project and removed the relevant code to ensure it runs smoothly. You can use the following command to install the modified version:
pip install git+https://github.com/EuDs63/ffmpy.git


https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/issues/16289#issuecomment-2255106490
option 2

RUN pip3 install -I --force-reinstall setuptools==71.0.0
RUN pip3 install --no-build-isolation --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/4519#issuecomment-2255358015
option 3

RUN echo "setuptools<72" > constraints.txt

ENV PIP_CONSTRAINT=constraints.txt

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && \
    poetry run pip install sqlalchemy==1.3.24 && \
    poetry install --no-cache && \


https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/4519#issuecomment-2255446798
option 4
pip3 install --no-build-isolation --no-cache-dir "setuptools<72"


Package version v72.0.0 has just been yanked (https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/72.0.0/).
If you replay your pipelines, the error should no longer pop up.

I've got this error too in my Dockerfile.
Workaround:
RUN echo "setuptools<72" > constraints.txt

ENV PIP_CONSTRAINT=constraints.txt

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && \
    poetry run pip install sqlalchemy==1.3.24 && \
    poetry install --no-cache && \

I could not understand why when I degraded the setuptools to version below 72.0.0 it kept cruising with the error of ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools.command.test'.

For Poetry users, even locking in setuptools<72 does not [always] seem to work. For some installations it still seems to use setuptools>=72 from somewhere, and the PIP_CONSTRAINT environment variable does not seem to be obeyed by poetry. A workaround here is:
$ poetry export -o requirements.txt
$ poetry export -o constraints.txt -f constraints.txt
$ PIP_CONSTRAINT="$(pwd)/constraints.txt" poetry run pip install -r requirements.txt

In other words, export your locked requirements to traditional pip requirements.txt and constraints.txt files, then run pip in the Poetry environment to install dependencies. This way it properly appears to obey the PIP_CONSTRAINT environment variable.
You can run poetry install afterwards and it should come up with nothing to do, meaning it had exactly the same effect as poetry install.
For the poetry export commands, make sure you add the same arguments as you'd add to poetry install, e.g. --only main.
If pip gives you an error like:
ERROR: Can't verify hashes for these requirements because we don't have a way to hash version control repositories: ...

Then add --without-hashes to the export commands.

Solution/workaround is there : https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/4519
If using docker and PIP or poetry, do the following :
RUN echo "setuptools<72" > constraints.txt
ENV PIP_CONSTRAINT=constraints.txt

(And you can then run your pip/poetry commands as normal)
If not, well, create a file constraints.txt at the root of your project with setuptools<72 as the file content
Then use export PIP_CONSTRAINT=constraints.txt to point to that file in the environnement variables.
Remove the fix once the upstream packages are updated

didn't solve for me using poetry

As a temporary workaround, try this:
pip install --upgrade pip-tools pip wheel
pip install setuptools==71.1.0

Run this before installing your packages.

Please install setuptools < 72.0.0 as tmp solution -> run installation for you package/library.
Bit, I think, adding setuptools as a dependency to poetry will work unstable, since all packages are installed in parallel (even in batches) and in this case the build will be non-deterministic (depending on what is installed first, the setup tool or the library)
echo "setuptools<72" > constraints.txt
export PIP_CONSTRAINT=constraints.txt

poetry run pip install <affected_package>==<version>
poetry install

